# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined Discord.js event guildMemberAdd

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

There is a problem with the command `send`, when the user logs in writes typeError, but the weird thing is that this command works, and it works when it works, before he sent commands, but as soon as you restart the bot, he starts so stupid.

[Code]

```
robot.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  try{
    let image_avatar = member.user.avatarURL()//{format: 'png', dynamic: true, size: 128}
    if(image_avatar == undefined){
      image_avatar = "https://discord.com/assets/dd4dbc0016779df1378e7812eabaa04d.png";
      //https://discord.com/assets/dd4dbc0016779df1378e7812eabaa04d.png
    }
    const block = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('PURPLE')
        .setTitle(`${member.displayName} добро пожаловать на сервер ${member.guild.name}`)
        .setDescription(`Рофлодарова, Дружочек-пирожочек, заходи и выбирай роль в ${robot.channels.cache.get(config.role_channel)}`)
        .setThumbnail(image_avatar)
        member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.get(config.userRole));
        member.guild.channels.cache.get(config.glav_channel).send(member.user, block);
  }catch(err){
    console.log(`[ERROR]: ${err}`)
  }
})
```

Error problem :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `config.glav_channel` is a valid channel ID but `channels.cache.get(config.glav_channel)` returns `undefined` it's probably because the channel is not cached yet. Try to [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) the channel instead. It returns a promise, so you'll need to resolve it first:

```js
robot.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
  try {
    const image_avatar = member.user.avatarURL() || 'https://discord.com/assets/dd4dbc0016779df1378e7812eabaa04d.png';
    const block = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('PURPLE')
      .setTitle(
        `${member.displayName} добро пожаловать на сервер ${member.guild.name}`,
      )
      .setDescription(
        `Рофлодарова, Дружочек-пирожочек, заходи и выбирай роль в ${robot.channels.cache.get(
          config.role_channel,
        )}`,
      )
      .setThumbnail(image_avatar);
    member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.get(config.userRole));

    const channel = await robot.channels.fetch(config.glav_channel);
    channel.send(member.user, block);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`[ERROR]: ${err}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: It's already added to the code above. `async (member) => { ...` and `const channel = await member...`

Comment: There is an additional problem: [ERROR]: TypeError: member.guild.channels.fetch is not a function

Comment: I've just updated my code, it should be `robot.channels.fetch()`